# Read non success http data in rebol

Tags: rebol, red

Is there a way to read non success http data, for example for a `404`, in Rebol? When `open` gets a non success http response code for an URL it fails with an error, but I would like to read the response instead.

Comment: I don't know the specific answer, but see [how to get the response content of an http 404 response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829211/how-to-get-the-response-content-of-an-http-404-response).  I think there should be a better answer, it's open source now, see [prot-http.r](https://github.com/rebol/rebol/blob/master/src/mezz/prot-http.r)!  :-)

Comment: Thanks @HostileFork! I don't know how I missed that question. Very enlightening. :) It's unfortunate that one needs to customize the http scheme for this. I haven't looked at the Rebol 3 code yet though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is crude, but it works for Rebol 2. You can get the http protocol scheme with

```
 h: get in system/schemes 'http
```

then you write it to a file

```
write %ht mold h
```

and edit this file. There you replace this line

```
result: select either tunnel [tunnel-actions] [response-actions] response-code
```

with

```
port/status: response-code 
result: case [
    tunnel [
       select tunnel-actions  response-code 
    ]
    not find response-actions response-code [
       return response-code
    ] 
    true [
      select response-actions response-code 
   ]
]
```

Then you have to replace the original scheme. Add
  `Rebol [] 
  system/schemes/http:`
at the beginnung of your ht-file and do it with `do %ht`

Comment: Yes, this works (in a very hackish way :) ). I see that the http scheme code doesn't quite do what I want without some custimization. What I'd really like is to get both data, response code and header for a request. Fortunately that code isn't too hard to write anyway.

Comment: I added the unhandled response codes at a place you can query.